# Trying to get the column populated for a scenario in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a scenario where my table looks like this,

```
    ID       cal                    planned date        
    1DE    26-jun-2020             08-Dec-2020           
    1DE    31-july-2020            17-feb-2020           
    1DE    24-aug-2020             17-feb-2020
```

Expected table

```
    ID       cal                    planned date         flag 
    1DE    26-jun-2020             08-Dec-2020           1
    1DE    31-july-2020            17-feb-2020           1
    1DE    24-aug-2020             17-feb-2020           0
```

I want to create a flag column where I compare the planned dates with its previous date. If there is a change in planned date for example here 08-Dec-2020 and 17-Feb-2020 have been changed so the flag has to be 1.  if the dates remain the same I need to add flag as 0.

Comment: how did you imagine the values of `planned date` within the result set ?

Comment: Sorry, it comes from the above table it was a mistake, check it now

Comment: I mean the logic behind for the output of those dates (`08-Dec-2020`,`17-feb-2023`)

Comment: It is just the way the dates are coming in. There are more dates to this column but I did not add them. Sorry, that I can not give out the logic behind these dates but all I wanted is about column fl.

Comment: Difficult to understand your question. Please reframe properly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `LEAD()` window function:

```
SELECT t.*,
  CASE 
    WHEN LEAD(t."planned date", 1, t."planned date") OVER (PARTITION By t."ID" ORDER BY t."planned date")
         = t."planned date" THEN 1 
    ELSE 0
  END flag     
FROM tablename t
ORDER BY t."cal"
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5ebd580bb05d569debbad3203604cd1a).
Results:

```
> ID  | cal       | planned date | FLAG
> :-- | :-------- | :----------- | ---:
> 1DE | 26-JUN-20 | 08-DEC-20    |    1
> 1DE | 31-JUL-20 | 17-FEB-20    |    1
> 1DE | 24-AUG-20 | 17-FEB-20    |    0
```

Comment: The result gives me other way around, I am getting 1 for same dates and 0 for different dates

Comment: @KSp I have only the sample data you posted and for this data as you can see in the demo you get your expected results. So maybe you should recheck the data and expected results you posted.

Comment: The logic works separately but not with the one I have. However, you answered what i asked for. Thanks

Comment: Is there any other way instead of using Lead? For me sometimes lead function is not working.

Comment: LEAD returns the next value of the column and there is also LAG that returns the previous.

Comment: Check the use of LAG: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0a3a30f6636d67614582b6da78ccfce4